# Finding the "discrete" difference between close floating point numbers

Tags: floating-point, numerical, x87

Suppose I have two floating point numbers, `x` and `y`, with their values being very close.

There's a discrete number of floating point numbers representable on a computer, so we can enumerate them in increasing order: `f_1, f_2, f_3, ...`.  I wish to find the distance of `x` and `y` in this list (i.e. are they 1, 2, 3, ... or `n` discrete steps apart?)

Is it possible to do this by only using arithmetic operations (`+-*/`), and not looking at the binary representation?  I'm primarily interested in how this works on x86.

Is the following approximation correct, assuming that `y > x` and  that `x` and `y` are only a few steps (say, < 100) apart? (Probably not ...)

```
(y-x) / x / eps
```

Here `eps` denotes the machine epsilon.  (The machine epsilon is the difference between 1.0 and the next smallest floating point number.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, that's why I divided by `x` too (not only `eps`). `(y-x) / x / eps = (y-x) / (x*eps)`. I'm still not sure it's correct though.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. Your formula may be right; let us think. :-) In the meantime you can read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://cr.yp.to/2005-590/goldberg.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Floats are lexicographically ordered, therefore:

```
int steps(float a, float b){

  int ai = *(int*)&a;  // reinterpret as integer
  int bi = *(int*)&b;  // reinterpret as integer
  return bi - ai;
}

steps(5.0e-1, 5.0000054e-1);  // returns 9
```

[Such a technique](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) is used when comparing floating point numbers.

Comment: as long as the numbers are > 0. Some logic is still needed to cover negative values and 0 (including the "-0").

Comment: +1, Interesting observation about lexicographic ordering.  What I'd really like to know though is still if this is possible using only floating point arithmetic operations.  The language I was using when I asked this doesn't support reinterpreting bit patterns as a different type.

Comment: @Szabolcs what language were you using?  I wrote the code in C++, but it should work in C and D.

Comment: My question was not really about how to do it in that language, I was merely curious if it can be done by using floating point operations only, without resorting to examining the bit-representation of the float in some way.  I was using Mathematica.  Even if not a direct answer to my question, you answer was interesting and I appreciate it (especially considering how old the question is).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to examine the binary representation directly, but you do have to rely on it to get an exact answer, I think.

Start by using [frexp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/frexp.html) to break x into exponent `exp` and mantissa.  I believe the next float bigger than x is `x + eps * 2^(exp-1)`.  (The "-1" is because frexp returns a mantissa in the range [1/2, 1) and not [1, 2).)

If x and y have the same exponent, you are basically done.  Otherwise you need to count how many steps there are per power of 2, which is just `1.0/eps`.  In other words, the number of steps between 2^n and 2^(n+1) is `1.0/eps`.

So, for y > x, count how many steps there are from x to the next power of two; then count how many more steps it takes to get to the largest power of 2 less than y; then count how many more steps it takes to get from there up to y.  All of these are pretty easily expressible in terms of `eps`, I think.