# How many distinct floating-point numbers in a specific range?

Tags: language-agnostic, ieee-754

How many rep­re­sentable floats are there be­tween `0.0` and `0.5`?  And how many representable floats are there between `0.5` and `1.0`?    I'm more interested in the math behind it, and I need the answer for `floats` and `doubles`.

Comment: hint: how many bits are used to represent that fractional range?

Comment: I don't remember the proof offhand, but you may find the answer in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html or http://floating-point-gui.de/ .

Comment: don't forget to count -0.0  :-)

Comment: this will depends totally of how many bits you have to represent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the "discrete" difference between close floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188822/finding-the-discrete-difference-between-close-floating-point-numbers). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0

Comment: 0.5 to 1.0 would be fairly easy to figure.  0.0 to 0.5 -- not so easy.

Comment: Also (very) closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015133/generating-random-floating-point-values-based-on-random-bit-stream

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For IEEE754 floats, this is fairly straight forward. Fire up the [Online Float Calculator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/) and read on.

All pure powers of 2 are represented by a mantissa `0`, which is actually `1.0` due to the implied leading 1. The exponent is corrected by a bias, so 1 and 0.5 are respectively 1.0 × 2<sup>0</sup> and 1.0 × 2<sup>−1</sup>, or in binary:

```
      S    Ex + 127    Mantissa - 1                Hex

1:    0    01111111    00000000000000000000000     0x3F800000
      +     0 + 127    1.0

0.5:  0    01111110    00000000000000000000000     0x3F000000
      +    -1 + 127    1.0
```

Since the floating point numbers represented in this form are ordered in the same order as their binary representation, we only need to take the difference of the integral value of the binary representation and conclude that there are 0x800000 = 2<sup>23</sup>, i.e. 8,388,608 single-precision floating point values in the interval [0.5, 1.0).

Similarly, the answer is 2<sup>52</sup> for `double` and 2<sup>63</sup> for `long double`.

Comment: ...and there are `0x3F000000` rep­re­sentable single-precision floats between `0.0` and `0.5`, which is over 1 billion.  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

A floating point number in IEEE754 format is between 0.0 (inclusive) and 0.5 (exclusive) if and only if the sign bit is 0 and the exponent is `< -1`. The mantissa bits can be arbitrary. For `float`, that makes `2^23` numbers per admissible exponent, for `double` 2^52. How many admissible exponents are there? For `float`, the minimal exponent for normalised numbers is -126, for `double` it's -1022, so there are

```
126*2^23 = 1056964608
```

`float` values in `[0, 0.5)` and

```
1022*2^52 = 4602678819172646912
```

`double` values.

Answer (score 2):

Kerrek gave the best explanation :)

Just in case here is the code to play with other intervals too
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a75ba5eceb49f84

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
unsigned long long int floatCount(T a, T b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return 0;

    if (a == b)
        return 1;

    unsigned long long int count = 1;

    while(a < b) {
        a = std::nextafter(a, b);
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "number of floats in [0.5..1.0] interval are " << floatCount(0.5f, 1.0f);    
}
```

prints

```
number of floats in [0.5..1.0] interval are 8388609
```

Answer (score 1):

For 0.0..0.5: you need to worry about exponents from -1 down to as low as possible, and then multiply how many you get time the number of distinct values you can represent in the mantissa.

For every value in that range, if you double it, you get a value in the range of 0.5..1.0.  And doubling it means just bumping up the exponent.

You also need to worry about unnormalized numbers, where the mantissa isn't used to represent 1.x, but 0.x, and thus will all be in your lower range, but can't be doubled by bumping up the exponent (since a particular value of the exponent is used to indicate that the value is unnormalized).

Comment: "For every value in that range, if you double it, you get a value in the range 0.5..1.0." eh no you need to *add* 0.5 which means that all numbers below `ulp(0.5)` will all become the same (0.5), for the 0.5..1 range all exponents are -1

Comment: Oops -- I was thinking about it in the other direction (going from the 0.5..1.0 range, and halving everything, which WOULD all map into the lower range).

Comment: yeah but it wouldn't have ALL numbers particularly those <0.25

Comment: Never said it was, but nice characterization of where the gap is.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per-se, but you might get some milage out of the [`nextafter`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/nextafter.html) function. Something like this ought to help you answer your question, though you'll have to work out the math yourself:

```
float f = 0;
while(f < 0.5)
  {
    print("%f (repr: 0x%x)\n", f, *(unsigned *)&f);
    f = nextafterf(f, 0.5);
  }
```

Comment: before you go attempting this **half** of the representable numbers in floating point are between -1 and 1 for a float that is 2 billion (or 1 billion between 0 and 1) for a double it that number *squared* if you start counting you'll be waiting for a while

Comment: @ratchetfreak - True, but if you don't know the underlying math (like me) you can probably start piecing together the pattern from the first twenty at most, and then all you really need to know is the start and end points. But yes, it's better if you know the math behind it.