# how many numbers between 0-1 can a 32bit floating point represent?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to figure out how many numbers between 0-1 can a 32bit floating point represent?
is it just  the same as in an interval? (2**24)-1

Comment: Hint: all positive numbers with a negative exponent will be between 0 and 1, regardless of the mantissa.

Comment: What floating-point format? IEEE 754 binary32 is (overwhelmingly) the most common 32-bit binary floating-point format, but it's not the only one.

Comment: About 25% of all `float`.

Comment: " is it just the same as in an interval? (2**24)-1" --> No.

Comment: Niv Peretz, "I'm trying to figure out how many  ...." --> Post your try.  So far, post does not show any attempt.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mean by "in an interval", since the number of floats in an interval would depend on the endpoints of that interval. But in a single *binade* (e.g., `[1.0, 2.0)`, or `[2.0, 4.0)`, etc.), and assuming IEEE 754 binary32, the number of values would be `2^23` rather than `2^24`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392678/298225) has C++ code to return the floating-point values in an interval, assuming IEEE-754 binary.

Answer (score 3):

That number happens to be 1,056,964,609. (Excluding -0). This only accounts for normal numbers. If you also include subnormals, then the number is 1,065,353,217. You can count them with a program like this:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   float x = 0.0f;
   int normals = 0;
   int all     = 0;

   while (x <= 1.0) {
     all++;
     if(isnormal(x)) normals++;
     x = nextafterf(x, 1.1);
   }

   printf("normals: %d\n", normals);
   printf("all    : %d\n", all);

   return 0;
}
```

When run, this prints:

```
normals: 1056964609
all    : 1065353217
```

It's interesting to note that a quarter of all normal floats live in this range. This is usually quite a surprise and can have implications in uniform random-number generation.

See https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/ for details.

Comment: That's excluding subnormals, right? (But incuding `0.0` and `1.0` (and excluding `-0.0`).)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Quite right; updated the answer to include denormals as well.

Comment: Note that 1,065,353,216 excludes one of 0 or 1.

Comment: The preferred term for numbers below the normal range is “subnormal”: These are numbers that are below the normal range, so they can only have denormalized representations. “Denormal” refers to a floating-point representation that is not normal. In IEEE-754 binary formats, the only denormalized representations are those for subnormal numbers. In decimal formats, numbers in the normal range can have normal or denormal representations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Quite right. Fixed the naming and also added a simple program to count the values.